# What is the smaller angle made by the two radial paths?

Tags: geometry

> Patty and Selma are racing through a park. The park has two concentric circular paths joined by two radial paths, one of which is at the point where they enter the park. The exit is at the intersection of the other radial path and the outer circle. Patty follows the radial path to the inner circle, walks around the short way to the other radial path and down it to the exit. Selma just walks the short way around the outer circle to the exit. They move at the same rate and meet up at the exit at the same time. What is the smaller angle made by the two radial paths?

This can be solved pretty easily by $\dfrac{x}{2\pi} \cdot 2\pi R = 2(R-r) + \dfrac{x}{2 \pi} \cdot 2\pi r$ to get $x = 2$ $\text{radians}$, but how do we know for sure that this is the smaller angle?

[image]

Comment: It will help if you add a drawing.

Comment: Because 2 is less than $\pi$?

Comment: The length of second path will be $2\pi R$ minus the length of the first path.